# Strange JavaScript code in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

How can I remove this code from Chrome browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apibrowsemarknet-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=isgiwhPL&amp;bp=PBG&amp;g=610d4e03-8817-4c82-99f7-20f50468c2ff" ></script></head>
```

Comment: Please provide more context, like the page you’re referring to etc.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this code?

Comment: Chrome is just installed without plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by one of several pieces of spyware.

Try looking for and removing these extensions from Chrome:
BetterSurf, LyricXeeker, HD-Plus, GetLyrics, DownloadTerms 1.0, Browse2Save, SuperLyrics, WebCake

Also, try removing the babylon toolbar from your computer through programs and features.

Although its not identical, [This site](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/rvzr2-a-akamaihd-net-removal/) and several others point to the akamaihd.net domain as a reporting portal for lots of spyware and the extensions I mentioned above are also mentioned in other sites.

FYI, i found this and many other pages by googling "Remove akamaihd.net"

Comment: I uninstalled all apps with ActiveX in name. It probably helped.